# setting multiple cookies on page load

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I struggle a lot with cookies in JavaScript, so I have used this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sACXO0n9Lgw). I used the 'create cookie function' but I am unsure about how to make a function that puts the cookies back into the text boxes on page load. I have looked at W3 Schools and still have no idea. Any ideas?

Here is the create cookie function I used which creates cookies from 'more than one' textbox.

```
function createCookie(nCookie){
var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setMonth(expDate.getMonth() + 12);
var cookieVal = document.getElementById(nCookie).value;
document.cookie = nCookie + "=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" +
expDate.toGMTString();}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to extract your cookies from document.cookie?

Comment: Yes, and I don't know how to put them into the right text box by id

Comment: Do you mean that your text boxes have id attribute set and you don't know how to fetch your textbox DOM elements by their id attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Working Example</h2>

    <form name="myForm" method="get" action="JavaScriptCookies.html" onsubmit="return storeValues(this);">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Field 1</label><span><input type="text" name="field1" value=""></span>
            <label>Field 2</label><span><input type="text" name="field2" value=""></span>
            <label>Field 3</label><span><input type="text" name="field3" value=""></span>
            <label>Field 4</label><span><input type="text" name="field4" value=""></span>
            <span>
                <input type="submit" value="Set Cookies">
                <input type="button" onclick="showCookies();" value="Retrieve Cookies">
            </span>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function storeValues(form)  
        {
            document.cookie = 'field1=' + form.field1.value;
            document.cookie = 'field2=' + form.field2.value;
            document.cookie = 'field3=' + form.field3.value;
            document.cookie = 'field4=' + form.field4.value;
            return true;
        }

        function showCookies() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                x = document.getElementsByName("field" + i);
                x[0].value = getCookie(x[0].name);
            }

            return true;
        }

        function getCookie(cname)
        {
            var name = cname + "=";

            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }

            return "";
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  if(field1 = getCookie("field1")) document.myForm.field1.value = field1;
  if(field2 = getCookie("field2")) document.myForm.field2.value = field2;
  if(field3 = getCookie("field3")) document.myForm.field3.value = field3;
  if(field4 = getCookie("field4")) document.myForm.field4.value = field4;
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a loop for this?

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

BTW if in the EU you need to declare cookie usage